# Unable to insert with blank value in MariaDB not in strict mode

Tags: mariadb, debian-stretch

I've just setup a new dev environment on Debian 9 and mariadb: 10.1.26-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 Debian 9.1

Previous environment was Debian 7 with mysql: 5.6.38-1~dotdeb+7.1 (Debian)

value for sql-mode is:

`MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';
+---------------+------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                  |
+---------------+------------------------+
| sql_mode      | NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+---------------+------------------------+`

For the databases, the columns are setup as NOT NULL with no default value. (most are just varchar / text fields)

I am unable to insert new records or change existing records. I am using laravel/eloquent and if I set the connection option to strict=true, I get an error about the column not having a default value instead.

All my research has turned up that I should be able to just turn strict mode off to get the old functionality back, however it does not appear that strict mode is on.

Is there a configuration option I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Finding a setting that allows imprecise code to continue to run isn't a great idea. One day eventually it will exhibit the wrong behaviour.

Fix your code to insert a value to all columns where it is set `NOT NULL` and no default value.

Alternately if there is a meaningful default value for a column, alter the table column to container the default value.